# Add new object to subdocument (but not replace)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add a new object to a subdocument where I know the 'ean' of it. I currently have the code below this this replaces the subdocument instead of adding to it, any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

```
  var info = {
    "merchant_id": 12354,
    "price_current": "test",
    "price_rrp": "test",
    "aff_link": "test",
    "merchant_product_id": 12345,
  }

  addUpdateMerchantToProduct: function(info) {

    var now = new Date();
    var query = { "ean" : 5055534336205};
    var update = { "merchants" : [{
      "merchant_id": info.merchant_id,
      "price_current": info.display_price,
      "price_rrp": info.rrp_price,
      "aff_link": info.aw_deep_link,
      "merchant_product_id": info.merchant_product_id,
      "aw_image_url": "",
      "cost_scoop": "",
      "created_at": now,
      "updated_at": now
    }]};

    Products.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function (err, product) {
      if (err) console.error(err);
    });

  }
```

Comment: See [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use $push.  Your update is being converted into a $set operator, which will replace the merchants field with an array containing a single object.

```
addUpdateMerchantToProduct: function(info) {

var now = new Date();
var query = { "ean" : 5055534336205};
var update = { 
    $push: {
        "merchants" : {
            "merchant_id": info.merchant_id,
            "price_current": info.display_price,
            "price_rrp": info.rrp_price,
            "aff_link": info.aw_deep_link,
            "merchant_product_id": info.merchant_product_id,
            "aw_image_url": "",
            "cost_scoop": "",
            "created_at": now,
            "updated_at": now
        }
    }
};

Products.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function (err, product) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
});
```